# When A is pressed mouse left button also pressed in SFML 2.0

Tags: c++, sfml

I had just started learning SFML 2.0 and I am facing a little bit problem. The problem is that when I press Button "A" then in Output it also show that "Mouse Left Button Pressed ".I am using code::block 16.04 and SFML 2.0.
Same thing happens with the "MouseWheelMoved" Event if i press any other number then it shows message that "MouseWheelMoved". Here is the code.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(400,400),"All Events ");
    sf::Event event;
    window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                switch(event.key.code)
                {
                case sf::Keyboard::A:
                    std::cout<<"A Button Pressed "<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::S:
                    std::cout<<"S Button Pressed "<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::D:
                    std::cout<<"D Button Pressed "<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::W:
                    std::cout<<"W Button Pressed "<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::Return:
                    std::cout<<"Enter Button Pressed"<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::Up:
                    std::cout<<"Up Button Pressed "<<std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                    if(event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)     {std::cout<<"Mouse Left Button Pressed "<<std::endl;
                    break;}
                    else if(event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right){std::cout<<"Mouse Right Button Pressed"<<std::endl;
                    break;}
                case sf::Event::MouseWheelMoved:
                    std::cout<<"Mouse Wheel Moved "<<event.mouseWheel.delta<<std::endl;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cases `sf::Event::KeyPressed` and `sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed` are cascading. Give it a _break_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `switch` nested, you are missing a break in one of them

```
switch(event.type) // switch 1
{
  // (...)
  case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
      switch(event.key.code) // switch 2
      {
      case sf::Keyboard::A:
          std::cout<<"A Button Pressed "<<std::endl;
          break; // <- this breaks switch 2 and...
      // (...)
      } 
      // ...you end up here. Here switch 1 doesn't have a break 
      // so it falls through to the next case.
      case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
        // (...)
        // here also falls through.
      case sf::Event::MouseWheelMoved:
          std::cout<<"Mouse Wheel Moved ";
          break;
}
```